# Привязка двух TextView по высоте

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть `RelativeLayout` с вложенным `LinearLayout`, который содержит два `TextView`, размещенных относительно друг друга по горизонтале. Это `DiscountAmount` и `AmountWithDiscount`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы `DiscountAmount` и `AmountWithDiscount` всегда располагались на одном уровне по вертикале, для этого у `LinearLayout` я выставил свойство `android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"`.  Но если `Name` слишком длинное и занимает три строчки, то оно налазит на `DiscountAmount`. Если  `Name` занимает не более 2-х строк то все хорошо.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить данную проблему?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutSaleListRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewRemoveRowSale"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30px"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutIncQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewRemoveRowSale"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewEditRowSale"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
    android:text="TextView" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDiscount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewRowDiscountAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRowAmountWithDiscount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
  </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewEditRowSale"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_45px"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_45px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit" />
```

Comment: Советую использовать ConstraintLayout, он удобнее и легче. Но и в Relative есть выравнивание по baseline, как раз для текста

Comment: Пробовал использовать ConstraintLayout, но проблема таже. ConstraintLayout тоже не дает сделать двойную привязку.

Comment: А если у нейм задать мин лайнс? чтобы он был не меньше чем. А линеар лайоут выравнивать только по нижней части нейм.

Comment: Если сделать android:minLines="3", то для тех случаев, когда Name занимает менее 3-х строк появляется пустая строка. Может есть более элегантное решение?!

Comment: А если сделать minLines = 2? Я вообще то это имел в виду. пустой строки не будет, а если появятся третья, четвертая, десятая строка, то Ваш лейаут поползет вниз. Я бы вообще выкинул линеар лейаут и сделала бы констрейнт лейаут. Первый текст вью выравнивал бы по низу нейма, а второй по бейслайну первого

Comment: А как в ConstraintLayout сделать область из TextView кликабельной? Сейчас я вешаю обработчик нажатия на relativeLayoutIncQuantity

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74857/discussion-between-iamthevoid-and-efremovav).

Comment: Реализовал через ConstraintLayout. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так на чистом `RelativeLayout` средний элемент вашей конструкции может выглядеть.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Name"
    android:lines="2"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowDiscountAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/textViewRowName"
    android:text="Discount Amount" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowAmountWithDiscount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textViewRowDiscountAmount"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Amount With Discount" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowQuantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/textViewRowDiscountAmount"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Row Quantity" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRowPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/textViewRowQuantity"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Row Price" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Детали сами допилите, что куда привязать иначе и т.п.

**PS** картинки вместе со средним элементом я бы сделал горизонтальным LinerLayout. У RelativeLayout есть проблема, он обрабатывается за два прохода, т.е. всегда медленнее других видов контейнеров.